# Получение JS со страницы с помощью Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

Использую $('.class').load('url #id'), но он загружает только html, как сделать, чтобы также подгружало недостающие скрипты(они есть в блоке #id, но на загруженной их нет)

```
$(window).hashchange( function(){
    // Alerts every time the hash changes!
            var linkmenuurl = $(location).attr('href').split("#!")[1]; 
            if(location.hash == ''){linkmenuurl ='';}
            if(sm==1 && selectedmenu !== linkmenuurl){
                $('.active').removeClass('active');
                $(elemthis).addClass('active');
                if($(elemthis).parent('.main-menu__item_level_1')){
                    $(elemthis).parent().parent().parent().children('.main-menu__item-link').addClass('active');}

                selectedmenu = linkmenuurl;
                sm=0;
                $('.new').load(linkmenuurl+' #lay_body_get', function(){
                    $('.new').show();
                    $('.lb2').css({top:$('.lb1').height()*-1-60});
                    $('.new').animate({left: 0},500 );
                    $('.old').animate({left: -1450},500, function() {
                        $('.old').addClass('ob1');
                        $('.new').addClass('nw1');
                        $('.ob1').removeClass('old').addClass('new').css({left:1450}).hide(100);
                        $('.nw1').removeClass('new').addClass('old').animate({top:0},100,function(){sm=1;});
                        $('.ob1').removeClass('ob1');
                        $('.nw1').removeClass('nw1');

                    });});} 
  })

  // Trigger the event (useful on page load).
  $(window).hashchange();

});
```

Comment: не стоит грузить скрипты таким образом.

Comment: Мне не обязательно таким образом, мне нужно чтобы загрузились не достающие скрипты которые находятся в блоке #id

Comment: Можете добавить более детализированный код?

Comment: Код добавил. Сайт, где используется http://vbtes.p.ht/Amira/

Comment: Например тут есть скрипты: http://vbtes.p.ht/Amira/contacts
А тут нету: http://vbtes.p.ht/Amira/#!contacts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше вынесите скрипты в отдельный файл и грузите через `$.getScript()`